# Running sparql query for getting float values

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Hi Below is my sparql query which I am executing on https://dbpedia.org/sparql. However I am getting an error "Invalid floating point value converting 'United States:'" because of the presence of some characters values in grossincome and If I change my query to str(?grossincome) as ?grossincome1) then it executes correctly. My question is how can I convert all currencies on same scale to avoid this error?

```
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>    
 PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
 PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
 PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

 select distinct (str(?resource) as ?movietitle) (xsd:float(?budget) as ?budget1) (xsd:float(?grossincome) as ?grossincome1) (str(?Country) as ?country1)  ?ReleaseDate where {
            ?movie foaf:name ?resource.
           ?movie dbo:budget ?budget.
           ?movie dbp:gross ?grossincome.
           ?movie dbp:country ?Country.
           ?movie dbo:releaseDate ?ReleaseDate.
           FILTER (lang(?resource) = 'en').
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in DBpedia is not perfect as you already recognized it's quite heterogeneous for the untyped property `dbp:gross`. Among others, it contains values like `BDT 2.52 crores`, `$34,994,648 USD`, `AU$178,000`, `6892098.0`, so it is almost impossible to handle different currencies via a SPARQL query such that it returns the values in the same currency.

I mean, you would have to know all different currencies and formats that occur and then handle each separately. But that's more the task of application logic and not the query itself.

Alternatively, you could try to use the data property `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/gross` instead, which is supposed to relate to values in $. At least that's what its label "gross ($)" states.